# How would you make it so a option goes back to a different menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Its not perfect I know but for the choices inbox, sent and spam I would like to make it so it returns to that menu instead of the main one.

Please help and thank you

```
def menu():

    print("""

    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>
    1.Sign In||2.Create Account|
    3.Exit   ||                |
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>
      """)


    ans=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":
        email()
    elif ans=="2":
        sign()
    elif ans=="3": 
        print("\n Goodbye") 
        ans = None
    else:
        print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")

import re
def email():
    email = input("Enter Your email: ")
    match = re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+.\w+', email)

    if match:
        print ("Valid email, Your are now logged in :D "), match.group()
        print("""

    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>
    1.Inbox||2.Spam             |
    3.Sent ||                   |
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>
      """)
    else:
        print ("Not valid,Try Again! ")

    choice=input("Pick Your Choice:")
    if choice=="1":
        inbox()
    elif choice=="2":
        spam()
    elif choice=="3":
        sent()
        choice = None
    else:
        print("Not valid,Try Again! ")

def sign():
    user = input('Create Email: ')
    password = input('Create Password: ')
    print("You have now created your account, go back to the menu to sign in!")
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to the menu")
    menu()
    store_user = [brandonbiba@gmail.com]
    store_pass = [brandon]

def inbox():
    print("You have no mail, come back later.")
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to the menu")
    menu()
def sent():
    print(" You have sent 1 piece of mail to m.mazi@gmail.com ")
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to the menu")
    menu()
import random
def spam():
 random.randrange(1,1000)
print("This is how much spam you have!")

menu()
```

Its not perfect I know but for the choices inbox, sent and spam I would like to make it so it returns to that menu instead of the main one.

Comment: Just make `menu()` a while loop that doesn't terminate until the user enters "3" to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can give control back to any function that called `inbox()` or `sent()`. Use `return` statements instead of calling `menu()` in the 2 functions above. Like this:

```
def inbox():
    print("You have no mail, come back later.")
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to the menu")
    return

def sent():
    print(" You have sent 1 piece of mail to m.mazi@gmail.com ")
    anykey=input("Enter anything to return to the menu")
    return
```

Comment: Thank you however the option where it has like 1. Inbox 2. Spam 3. Sent how would i create a code which makes it go back to that instead of the 1. sign in menu